# Parse a string of length at least one character

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a parser in Haskell. In this I need a function that parses a string of length at least 1. I have the type declared below:

```
type Pname = String
```

but my function that I have doesn't work. The code I have is below, where `sc` is my space consumer for whitespace and comments (I have been following the tutorial at https://mrkkrp.github.io/megaparsec/tutorials/parsing-simple-imperative-language.html for help with this parser):

```
pname :: Parser Pname
pname = (some ['a' .. 'z']) <* sc
```

but it gives me the error:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘[]’
                   with ‘ParsecT Dec String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’
    Expected type: ParsecT
                     Dec String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Char
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the first argument of ‘some’, namely ‘['a' .. 'z']’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*)’, namely ‘(some ['a' .. 'z'])’
    In the expression: (some ['a' .. 'z']) <* sc
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you meant to use [`oneOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:oneOf) (or a similar function from your parser library) as in

```
pname = some (oneOf ['a' .. 'z']) <* sc
```

to turn the list of characters into a parser that accepts one of those characters.

Comment: I need it to accept one or more characters, hence I don't believe oneOf is suitable?

Comment: @datguywelbz `oneOf ['a' .. 'z']` accepts exactly one character; but `some (oneOf ['a' .. 'z'])` accepts one or more (see the [documentation for `some`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:some)).